# Why is my mac using 450mb swap when I have more than 16gb free

Tags: mac, memory, memory-management

I wonder why my mac is using 450mb+ swap when there's lots of free ram. I don't understand why it would decide to use swap instead of ram when there's so much of it free.

I imagine the proces using swap would run faster when it would just use the free ram right?

I'm just curious, not that my mac runs slow or anything it's fine haha.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't actually tell you how much swap is being used right now. It's a high-tide marker.

I'd call it a non-issue. At some point since your last reboot, it needed some swap. Not much & not enough to worry about.

Memory pressure is green, that's really all that counts.

Comment: Basically, there's always a swap/page file, even if you're with lots of RAM. It's to prevent apps that need this from crashing, or also to prevent delay if there's a need for more RAM than you're physical. They don't need to create one on the fly.

Comment: @NatsuKage - there always **is** one, sure - but actually the Mac is far better at *not* using it than Windows is. If you do have plenty of RAM it is quite rare to see it used at all. I have 64GB here & maybe only see it used once or twice a year, usually after I've been doing something stupidly memory-heavy. This is mine after only 5 days' uptime. I can easily go 40 or so without ever seeing it register any usage - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYYHw.png It's still really a non-issue, so long as the pressure stays green.

Comment: For some reason, my MBP is occasionally using swap even though I have 64GB of RAM and 20GB free. Seems strange.